# Invoke web-services in JSF

Tags: java, web-services, jsf

I need to write invoker for web services in JSF.
Any guidlines you can give me? Which lib(API) should I use?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The way you access web services from your code (managed beans perhaps?) does not depend on JSF. [CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) and [Metro](https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/) are both implementations of JAX-WS, using which you can implement web-service client code.

Comment: and alone I cant write client for invoking WS? Why using CFX and Metro?

Comment: of course you can, if you want to do everything by hand and reinvent the wheel. Using them allows you to write/generate a client in a few steps and a few lines of code

Comment: OK, I decided to try CXF. So I downloaded the binary distribution of apache cfx and the all jars in the lib folder I put in my WEB-INF/lib folder in the project in Eclipse. Am I doing good? Its the right way of using the CXF in Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, it is. (There are _better_ ways, but they require additional expertise, like maven or ivy)

Comment: when I run this:
JaxWsDynamicClientFactory dcf = JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.newInstance();
Client client = dcf.createClient("http://ws.strikeiron.com/IPLookup2?WSDL");
I got some error like this:
No Factories configured for this Application. This happens if the faces-initialization does not work at all - make sure ....

i should configure somehow my JSF web.xml?

Comment: JSF has nothing to do with this. I'd suggest reading the how-to guide, and if something doesn't work, ask another question.

Comment: I found it difficult to write dynamic client with CXF. I recieve some error that I cant solve. Any other way of writting dynamic clients?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement web services clients dynamically using CXF library.

In order to avoid some error like **"No Factories configured for this Application"** using a CXF Dynamic Client and JSF, you must to do something like this:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
JaxWsDynamicClientFactory dcf = JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.newInstance();
Client client = dcf.createClient("ws.strikeiron.com/IPLookup2?WSDL");
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(classLoader);
```